# Minimum requirements for private chain miner

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

We are currently building a model with raspberry pi 3 to demonstrate a usecase in our university. When we try to run a miner on the raspberry pi 3 it crashes when creating a new block.

We want to look for a small atx-board to take over the mining, however we don't know what the minimum requirements are for a private ethereum blockchain.

Our genesis configuration set the difficulty at 400 and we changed the geth-function so the difficulty stays the same.

Any pointers or recommendations would help!

Comment: `geth` should not crash when creating a block. What's the error? Are your code changes public?

Comment: "geth crashes" is not something a serious developer would say. You have post the backtrace at least. No pointers or recommendations can be given to such question.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a PoW network on Raspberry Pi's if you have programmed the difficulty to stay the same? It's incredibly likely (in fact, I'm almost willing to bet) that geth is crashing due to the modifications you made. Given that you are using relatively low powered devices, and a constant difficulty, why are you using PoW? Your situation sounds like the *perfect* use case for PoA chains.